# Facing issue in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

I am facing issue in java while date formatting.
For all the other dates, this format is working fine. But for below date `Thu Jan 06 03:30:51 IST 2022` when i use SimpleDateFormat I am getting below date as Output `2022-12-31T03:30:51` . Issue is Instead of year 2021 I am getting year as 2022

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = new Date(122,0,6,3,30,51);//Thu Jan 06 03:30:51 IST 2022
        date = DateUtils.addDays(date, -6);//Fri Dec 31 03:30:51 IST 2021
        targetFormat.format(date);//2022-12-31T03:30:51 
    }
```

Please guide me

Comment: It took me a while to notice your problem is that the year you're getting is 2022 instead of the expected 2011. You may want to [edit] your question and make that a bit more clear.

Comment: `Y` in the SimpleDateFormat class refers to `Week year`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html - You probably want to use `y` (lower case) to get the normal year.

Comment: By the way, don't use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Use the newer classes from the `java.time` package. In your case probably `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);`

"`YYYY`" is week-based calendar year.

"`yyyy`" is ordinary calendar year.

You can read this if you want to know more :

https://dev.to/shane/yyyy-vs-yyyy-the-day-the-java-date-formatter-hurt-my-brain-4527

Answer (score 0):

If you use java 8 or higher, please don't use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes. They are badly outdated and `SimpleDateFormat` especially has a lot of nasty problems. See package [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and read about it. As for your classes you will need to use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class and [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class (or some other implementation of [Temporal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) interface)

Comment: Ok, but how does this answer the question? They'll still need to write a pattern and they will write it with the same error even if they use a different API.